# How to access playlist created by Google's Play Music app?

Tags: android, playlist, android-music-player

How can I find a list of playlists created by Google's Music Play application (it is a default one on Galaxy Nexus for example).

Solution presented in [How can I access playlist created by android default music app and call the music app to play it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370278/how-can-i-access-playlist-created-by-android-default-music-app-and-call-the-musi) doesn't work - it shows only playlists that were created outside of the application and copied to phone.

Any ideas?