# cannot get playlist created in Google Play Music

Tags: android, playlist

I created two playlist in Google Play Music but it seems like if no playlist has been found.
I'm using the code found in this topic.

[How can I access playlist created by android default music app and call the music app to play it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370278/how-can-i-access-playlist-created-by-android-default-music-app-and-call-the-musi?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Thank you for your help guys

Answer (score 4):

You can use those code only for music players which use default Android media storage. But Google Play Music has it's own database. That's why you need different uri and column names.

To get a list of playlists I use following code:

```
Uri playlistsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/playlists");
Cursor playlists = context.getContentResolver().query(playlistsUri, new String[]{"_id", "playlist_name"}, null, null, null);
```

Then you can get song id which is relevant to song id in default Android media storage. After that you can play songs directly or get songs details to do anything with it.

```
Uri songsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/playlists/" + playlistId + "/members");
context.getContentResolver().query(songsUri, new String[]{"SourceId", "hasLocal"}, null, null, null);
```

To get a song details from default media storage on Android you should use something like this:

```
Cursor songDetailsCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA},
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + " = " + songId,
                null, null);
```

Comment: The first query only returns one record. i.e, the last created playlist.