# How to save audio globally to access it with the native music app

Tags: android, react-native, mediastore

I've scrolled through [various questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370278/how-can-i-access-playlist-created-by-android-default-music-app-and-call-the-musi) on the topic which all answer on how to retrieve the list of songs stored on the device but is there a way to add a song to the **mediastore**? For example if I have an audio file, How can I save that to disk and then be able to access it through the native music player?

I've tried to save to the following path

> Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getAbsolutePath()`

But that seems to store the file at the app level and I cannot access it with the music app. I've scrolled through the [MediaStore.Audio](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio) docs but cannot find anything.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @parekhkruti26 Well its a react native app all I do is save the music file to the path obtained by the constant I posted, but I do not see them in the native app. So I am unsure whether its an error on my part or whether the directory that it writes to is the wrong one for that.